# tJavaFlex Unparseable Date in Talend Open Studio

Tags: java, talend

I have a talend job in which I am trying to convert a date string in MM/DD/YYYY format to: YYYYMM format.

I created a component tJavaFlex and added the below snippet.

```
java.util.Date MTDdate = new     SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM").parse(context.ReportMonthStr);
context.CurrentMonthMTDDate = MTDdate;
System.out.println("\tCurrentMonthMTDDate="+context.CurrentMonthMTDDate);
```

Which is throwing the below error:

```
Exception in component tJavaFlex_1
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "05/01/2016"

I thought we can use the SimpleDateFormat within tFlex for date conversions.  What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to convert to YYYYMM format?
```

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

If the input date format is `05/01/2016` then you cannot parse it with `SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM")`.  The format has to match the actual input.  Once you have parsed the date in its original format you are free to reformat it any way you like.